# Handle two APIs at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to load planet data from an API using React and put this data into a Material UI card component. Unfortunately the planet API I'm using doesn't have photographs, which I want to also display in the card. For this, I'm using another API.

API for fetching planet data: https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest
API for fetching planet images: https://images-api.nasa.gov/search

I have figured out how to render each planet component with its respective info into a card, but don't know how to map each NASA image to the respective planet:

This is the code for the **App.js** component:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import Block from "./Block"


function App() {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([])
  const [images, setImages] =useState([])
 
  const getPlanets = async()=>{
    const data = await fetch
    ('https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies') //Await for first fetch promise to resolve
    const planets = await(data.json()) //Await for data.json to resolve and save this planets

    setPlanets(planets.bodies.filter 
        (planet =>planet.isPlanet && planet.name.indexOf('1')===-1)) 
  }

  const getImages = (name)=>{
    axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search',{
      params:{
        q: name
      }
    })
    .then(res => 
      setImages(images.concat(res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href)))
  } 

  console.log(planets)   

  useEffect(()=>{
    getPlanets();
  },[])
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(planets){
      planets.map(planet =>getImages(planet.englishName))
    }
  },[])

 console.log(images)
 console.log(planets.length)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {planets.map(planet => 
        (<Block 
          key = {planet.id}
          id = {planet.id}
          name = {planet.englishName}
          dateDiscovered = {planet.discoveryDate}
          mass = {planet.mass.massValue}
          massExp = {planet.mass.massExponent}
          image = ???
        />)
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The code for **Block.js** is as follows:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './Block.css'

import {Card, CardContent} from '@material-ui/core'
function Block(props){
    return (
        <div>
            <Card>
                <CardContent>
                    <div className = "planetInfo">
                        <h4>{props.name}</h4>
                        <h5>Mass: {props.mass}*10^{props.massExp} kg</h5>
                        <h5>Discovery Date: {props.dateDiscovered}</h5>
                        <h5>ID: {props.id}</h5>
                        <img src = {props.image}/>
                    </div>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Block
```

I have a feeling my structure isn't right. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON for a planet and images. (from your console.logs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `useEffect` and when the planets array changes, then you could iterate through the name of the planets in the planets array and call the image API.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchAllImages() {
    const allImages = [];

    for await (const planet of planets) {
      const { data }  = axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search',{
      params:{
        q: planet.name
      }})

      allImages.push(data);
    }

    setImages(allImages);
  }

  fetchAllImages();
}, [planets])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily map planets and images based on their array index - given that:

> you retrieve them in order

And since there are 8 planets there will be 8 images; So your `Array.map` function will look like:

```
 {planets.map((planet,index) => 
  (<Block 
  key = {planet.id}
  id = {planet.id}
  name = {planet.englishName}
  dateDiscovered = {planet.discoveryDate}
  mass = {planet.mass.massValue}
  massExp = {planet.mass.massExponent}
  image = images[index]
  
  />))}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a really difficult problem to handle multiple API calls together. I don't exactly know if this will work but why don't you change
`const [images, setImages] =useState([])` to   `const [images, setImages] =useState({})`  and

```
  axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search',{
 
 params:{
  q: name

 }})
 .then(res => setImages(images.concat(res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href)))
}
```

to

```
  axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search',{
 
 params:{
  q: name

 }})
 .then(res =>{ 
         images[name] = res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href));
         setImages({...images});
     })
}
```

Then you can loop with `planets` array picking URLs from `images` object based on plant name.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest combining the two data fetches into a single effect hook callback. First fetch and filter the list of celestial bodies for true planets, then fetch the images and map the planets and images into a single array of planet data. Now simply pass `image={planet.image}` to `Block`.

```
function App() {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([]);

  const getPlanets = async () => {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies"); //Await for first fetch promise to resolve
    const planets = await data.json(); //Await for data.json to resolve and save this planets

    // filter planet data
    const filteredPlanets = planets.bodies.filter(
      (planet) => planet.isPlanet && planet.name.indexOf("1") === -1
    );

    // define function here to avoid needing it as dependency
    // return GET request response image value
    const getImages = (name) => {
      return axios
        .get("https://images-api.nasa.gov/search", {
          params: {
            q: name
          }
        })
        .then((res) => res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href);
    };

    // Fetch and await all images
    const planetImages = await Promise.all(
      filteredPlanets.map((planet) => getImages(planet.englishName))
    );

    // Merge planets and images arrays
    const planetsWithImages = filteredPlanets.map((planet, i) => ({
      ...planet,
      image: planetImages[i]
    }));

    setPlanets(planetsWithImages);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getPlanets();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {planets.map((planet) => (
        <Block
          key={planet.id}
          id={planet.id}
          name={planet.englishName}
          dateDiscovered={planet.discoveryDate}
          mass={planet.mass.massValue}
          massExp={planet.mass.massExponent}
          image={planet.image} // <-- pass planet.image
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit handle-two-apis-at-the-same-time]

Answer (score 1):

I would add the images to the planet array, and remove the images array altogether.

On these lines...

```
    if(planets){
     planets.map(planet =>getImages(planet.englishName))
    }
   
  },[])
```

Your `getImages` function is fetching and storing the images in `images`

But since you are already mapping through your planets to get the planet names, instead of storing those images in a separate variable, return/store them in the planets array.

Maybe something like this...

```
if(planets){
    planets.map(planet => {
      const image = getImages(planet.englishName)
      return {...planet, image}
    })
  },[])
```

So now this line `image = ???` is `image = planet.image`

And maybe do it all with one `useEffect` with something like this...

```
const getPlanets = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies')
  const data = await data.json()
  const planets = data.bodies.filter(planet =>planet.isPlanet && planet.name.indexOf('1') === -1)
    
  return planets
}      
 
const getImages = async (name) => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search', {params:{q: name}})
  const images = response.concat(res.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href)

  return images
}


useEffect(()=>{
      getPlanets()
        .then(planets => Promise.all(planets.map(async (planet) => {
          const image = await getImages(planet.englishName)
          return  {...planet, image }
        })))
        .then(planets => setPlanets(planets))
  },[])
```

*note I have not tested the above code but hopefully close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios'
import Block from "./Block"


function App() {
  const [planets, setPlanets] = useState([])
  const [images, setImages] =useState([])
 

  const getPlanets = async()=>{
    const data = await fetch
    ('https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies') //Await for first fetch promise to resolve
    const planets = await(data.json()) //Await for data.json to resolve and save this planets

    setPlanets(planets.bodies.filter 
        (planet =>planet.isPlanet && planet.name.indexOf('1')===-1)) 
    }      
 

  useEffect(()=>{
      getPlanets();
  },[])
  

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAllImages() {
      const allImages = [];
  
      for await (const planet of planets) {
        const data  = await axios.get('https://images-api.nasa.gov/search',{
        params:{
          q: planet.englishName
        }})
        const res = await data.data.collection.items[0].links[0].href
        allImages.push(res);
      }
  
      setImages(allImages);
     

    }
  
    fetchAllImages();
  }, [planets])
  console.log(images)

  return (
    
   <div className="App">
     
 {planets.map((planet,index) => 
  (<Block 
  key = {planet.id}
  id = {planet.id}
  name = {planet.englishName}
  dateDiscovered = {planet.discoveryDate}
  mass = {planet.mass.massValue}
  massExp = {planet.mass.massExponent}
  image = {images[index]}
  
  />))}
  
   </div>
   
  );

}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for for your help. Turns out it was a combination of properly creating the images array, and using an index for mapping.